# I want to use hylafax email to fax service in php from my server. Hylafax is installed on other server. Is there any way to achieve this?

Tags: php

I have to fax some documents using hylafax email to fax service. I am using PHP in my application. But hylafax is installed on the other server of which we have access. Is there any way to achieve this? I am not able to get from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to achieve this?

Yes. There are ways.

Comment: I need steps to set up email to fax integration i.e. attaching documents in gmail and sending it to hylafax server

Comment: Then you will need to do some research. No one here is going to provide all of the steps for you.